# Cayley Table of the Dihedral Group \$D_3\$

Tags: code-golf, math

The [Dihedral group \$D_3\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6) represents the symmetries of an equilateral triangle, using the identity (represented by `id`), rotations (represented by `r1` and `r2`), and reflections (represented by `s0`, `s1`, and `s2`).

Your task is to compute the composition \$yx\$ of the elements \$x, y \in D_3 \$. They are given by the Cayley table below:

```
  x  id  r1  r2  s0  s1  s2
y  +-----------------------
id | id  r1  r2  s0  s1  s2
r1 | r1  r2  id  s1  s2  s0
r2 | r2  id  r1  s2  s0  s1
s0 | s0  s2  s1  id  r2  r1
s1 | s1  s0  s2  r1  id  r2
s2 | s2  s1  s0  r2  r1  id
```

#### Input

Any reasonable input of `x` and `y`. Order does not matter.

#### Output

`y` composed with `x`, or looking up values in the table based on `x` and `y`.

#### Test Cases

These are given in the form `x y -> yx`.

```
id id -> id
s1 s2 -> r1
r1 r1 -> r2
r2 r1 -> id
s0 id -> s0
id s0 -> s0
```

#### Notes on I/O

You may use any reasonable replacement of `id, r1, r2, s0, s1, s2`, for example `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, or even `[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2]` (here the first number represents rotation/reflection and the second is the index).

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda o,O:[o[_]for _ in O]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDdioMwEIWvzVMcvKqQguZScF@hD5AGsZiwQquS2KKUPrudidtuezPMfJwzf@My/Q69Wl11XM/N5dQ2GOSh1IOujRs8anQ9Dmbtm4sNqKDTrk0lUl/EqDiGPMZIgkqNYPHUnM6WDHeRsKWEziUKCWUkEbIT4VIi34hiwiXJIqG2myZ/uULx10e9NS8Xy4x4CNFaB29v1gdb8x67MStFwqdwxdfEU4glncN7U82ZQVVhLMk/Xf0mFIKt86ePwfLVaPRdP2GWWOgD@x/6w9cGbvc/ZjbyY@hismx9Ag)

Comment: can u explain this code?

Comment: @taritgoswami Both `o` and `O` are three-element lists containing a permutation of the integers `0, 1, 2`. In the list comprehension, the former is indexed by the latter, implementing permutation composition.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

Uses the following mapping:

```
 id | r1 | r2 | s0 | s1 | s2
----+----+----+----+----+----
 2  | 0  | 4  | 1  | 3  | 5
```

Takes input as `(x)(y)`.

```javascript
x=>y=>'450123234523012323'[(x*51^y)%18]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrdCoMgHAXw@z3F/2aow0VqwmAY1GuIg@hjFC1Dx9Cnd2Q3hx/nnKX7db538/69b3YY06RSUHVUNapkybjgopJcnEIah5tkr0iu7GFSAwo0cAolhYoCoyAoSDDPS5sX5BiigHx55Dxk58bxbI6Ob283b9exWO0bN8Wn23EEVcPJcLDVEw4ER2IIIekP)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 20 bytes

Using [Jonathan Frech's I/O format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171966/58563):

```javascript
x=>y=>y.map(n=>x[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrdCoMgHAXw@z3F/2aow0VqwmAY1GuIg@hjFC1Dx9Cnd2Q3hx/nnKX7db538/69b3YY06RSUHVUNapkybjgopJcnEIah5tkr0iu7GFSAwo0cAolhYoCoyAoSDDPS5sX5BiigHx55Dxk58bxbI6Ob283b9exWO0bN8Wn23EEVcPJcLDVEw4ER2IIIekP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ị
```

A dyadic link taking y on the left and x on the right.

Uses the representations of the fist three natural numbers transformed as their actions describe:

```
   name:  id          r1          r2          s0          s1          s2
  value:  [1,2,3]     [2,3,1]     [3,1,2]     [2,1,3]     [1,3,2]     [3,2,1]
(action:  identity    rot-Left    rot-Right   swap-Left   swap-Right  swap-Outer)
```

A port of 
[Jonathan Frech's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171966/53748)

`ị` is Jelly's "index into" atom, and it vectorises; note that Jelly is 1-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7///9HG@sY6hjF/o820gGyYgE)** Or see [a table using the question-names](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7/h5c7HN6XkOnwqGkNCDXuAAq6//8fHW2oY6RjHKujEA2kdAxBDCClYwQRMYRIASmICJACqon9H62UmaKkowAESkWGMIYRlFFsAGPApIqNlIBULAA).

---

To take x on the left and y on the right, these values may be used instead:

```
id       r1       r2       s0       s1       s2
[1,2,3]  [3,1,2]  [2,3,1]  [1,3,2]  [3,2,1]  [2,1,3]
```

...[see here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7/h5cf3peQ6fCoaQ0INe4Airn//x8dbahjpGMcq6MQbawDZIIYQL6OIYhhCGQYQaSMICJACqg49n@0UmaKko4CECgVGcIYRlBGsQGMAZMqNlICUrEA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:(y+x*5**y)%6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc2xCoMwFIXhuXmKQ6Cg6R00rR0EnyTNkGJDBY0SbUmePsU4dPk5wwdnidt7djLZ7pFGMz17g0CxLeIliEaIWJ7vyZnptaKD4kPPCXyt9vo671wv85Zcs68ZP4euCJJwI9SEK6HRjNnZI2JwOFTLTosf3AaVL5QtAiGWGrsLf6fTDw) Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @NieDzejkob. Uses the following mapping:

```python
 id | r1 | r2 | s0 | s1 | s2 
----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 1  | 3  | 5
```

Comment: @JonathanFrech ... I don't have `x*-1`... I have `x*(-1**y)`

Comment: @JonathanFrech Ah, I'd typoed my test code, I thought I was getting `(-1)**y`. Oh well, that's still 1 byte shorter...

Comment: Hm ... And I thought I golfed a byte ...

Comment: Like on the D4 challenge, you can replace `(-1)` with 5 for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
+.×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/04Cktt7h6f//Z6YAmY86ZujZPupd8ah3s7HCo@4WhSJDoKjho569mSkQvhGQb4TgFxuAdCG4MOXFBhA@THmxAZc7kAlUVmQINASoD6gWKM2lnpmirqBeZAgijIBEsQGIAHGLjdSj3YEOedTbCXJWGtBZ7rEA)

`+.×` is matrix multiplication

we represent the group as

```apl
id     r1     r2     s0     s1     s2
1 0 0  0 0 1  0 1 0  0 0 1  0 1 0  1 0 0 
0 1 0  1 0 0  0 0 1  0 1 0  1 0 0  0 0 1 
0 0 1  0 1 0  1 0 0  1 0 0  0 0 1  0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 1 byte

```
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7n2aloeCgoPk/ITMlocgwocgoodggodgwodjIoVpLLb0uxqqiVl1dO10hTd8qxirdSsNAwVDByBqIFQysgVjBEEgaAtlADBQHYgVDzf//AQ)

`x@y` is list indexing, which is the same as composition of permutations; we represent the group as

```
id:0 1 2; r1:1 2 0; r2:2 0 1; s0:2 1 0; s1:1 0 2; s2:0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

Uses [Jonathan's I/O format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171966/58974).

```
gV
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osKPkfYhsdYqhjpAPEIUZAliGQBPOArNjDm4w10zUCbJUyU4oMi4yKDYoNi42UDm/STArlCkkPSAr7nx72PyA9JCk1/L9SkaESlxJQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```javascript
(x,y)=>(y+x*5**y)%6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1LCoMwGATgfU8xm5LE/hVNazclgl5DXAQfRbFGklLM6VNMN8MHMzCz/mrX2Wn7XFfTD2FUge/khSq5v@xJkSRenB@hgkKDjCAJd0JOuBEKtM9THRs29YzAXHakzaNjWhkt2bHtzOrMMqSLefEqfeuNe6gSf@4H62aM960QIvwA) Edit: Saved 2 bytes by switching to `**` and 3 bytes thanks to @NieDzejkob. Uses the following mapping:

```javascript
 id | r1 | r2 | s0 | s1 | s2 
----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 1  | 3  | 5
```

The old 24 byte version also works in old versions of JavaScript:

```javascript
(x,y)=>(y%2?y+6-x:y+x)%6
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```
(lambda(x y)(modulo(+ y(* x(expt 5 y)))6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvNCoAgEAbvPcUHXXbrFFTvs6WGtP1gBvr0Jh1nhgmy7jaWVuXcEH5oyFjnTwtXSOVYjFBCZjou8@pFPTJ1SGTTHTHVwDwzF27q559bJYMcRgxVfg)

A boring port of Neil's Python answer. Uses the same I/O format, so:

```
 id | r1 | r2 | s0 | s1 | s2 
----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 1  | 3  | 5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
Mod[#+#2*5^#,6]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d83PyVaWVvZSMs0TlnHLFbtf7ShjoJJbOx/AA)

Another boring port of Neil's answer, this time in Mathematica. It is an anonymous function that takes arguments in the order `[y, x]`.

Here’s the input representation:

```
 id | r1 | r2 | s0 | s1 | s2 
----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 1  | 3  | 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
è
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171972/52210), but with 0-based indices, so the representations are:

```python
id       r1       r2       s0       s1       s2       # Original values
[0,1,2]  [1,2,0]  [2,0,1]  [1,0,2]  [0,2,1]  [2,1,0]  # Values instead
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Ir//6ONdAx0DGO5og11gKxYAA) or [verify all possible combinations](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eO7RyYdWllWGHlpXplRhq2Qf4WKvZK1QCWRVAlkKj9omKSjZ/z@84r/OfwA) or [verify all mapped back to ids](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/0qGFOZkqxYbFBkWGRUbERkGt0eEvxoXVexV7Zh1cohXEZHZ57dPKhlWWVoYfWlSlV2CrZR7hE6oXZK1krVAI5lRCOwqO2SQpK9v8Pr/gP5Ov8BwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
è  # Index the second (implicit) input-list vectorized into the first (implicit) input-list
   # And output the result implicitly
```