# Dihedral group D4 composition with custom labels

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, permutations, abstract-algebra

The dihedral group \$D_4\$ is the [symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) of the square, that is the moves that transform a square to itself via rotations and reflections. It consists of 8 elements: rotations by 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees, and reflections across the horizontal, vertical, and two diagonal axes.

[image: The 8 elements of D4 acting on the square.]

*The images are all from [this lovely page](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/symmetric/D4example.htm) by Larry Riddle.*

This challenge is about composing these moves: given two moves, output the move that's equivalent to doing them one after another. For instance, doing move 7 followed by move 4 is the same as doing move 5.

[image: Composition example]

Note that switching the order to move 4 then move 7 produces move 6 instead.

The results are tabulated below; this is the [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) of the group \$D_4\$. So for example, inputs \$7, 4\$ should produce output \$5\$.

\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {} & {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
\end{array} }  \\ 
   {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1  \\ 
   2  \\ 
   3  \\ 
   4  \\ 
   5  \\ 
   6  \\ 
   7   \\
   8   \\
\end{array} } & {\boxed{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
   2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 6\\ 
   3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7\\ 
   4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 5\\ 
   5 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4\\ 
   6 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\ 
   7 & 6 & 8 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3\\ 
   8 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1\\ 
\end{array} }}  \\ 
\end{array}

**Challenge**

Your goal is to implement this operation in as few bytes as possible, but in addition to the code, **you also choose the labels** that represent the moves 1 through 8. The labels must be *8 distinct numbers from 0 to 255*, or the 8 one-byte characters their code points represent.

Your code will be given two of the labels from the 8 you've chosen, and must output the label that corresponds to their composition in the dihedral group \$D_4\$.

**Example**

Say you've chosen the characters C, O, M, P, U, T, E, R for moves 1 through 8 respectively. Then, your code should implement this table.

\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {} & {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \, C  \, & \, O \, & M \, & P \, & U \, & \, T \, &  \, E \,  &  R \, \\ 
\end{array} }  \\ 
   {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   C  \\ 
   O  \\ 
   M  \\ 
   P  \\ 
   U  \\ 
   T  \\ 
   E   \\
   R   \\
\end{array} } & {\boxed{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   C & O & M & P & U & T & E & R \\ 
   O & M & P & C & R & E & U & T\\ 
   M & P & C & O & T & U & R & E\\ 
   P & C & O & M & E & R & T & U\\ 
   U & E & T & R & C & M & O & P\\ 
   T & R & U & E & M & C & P & O\\ 
   E & T & R & U & P & O & C & M\\ 
   R & U & E & T & O & P & M & C\\ 
\end{array} }}  \\ 
\end{array}

Given inputs E and P, you should output U. Your inputs will always be two of the letters C, O, M, P, U, T, E, R, and your output should always be one of these letters.

**Text table for copying**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 1 8 7 5 6
3 4 1 2 6 5 8 7
4 1 2 3 7 8 6 5
5 7 6 8 1 3 2 4
6 8 5 7 3 1 4 2
7 6 8 5 4 2 1 3
8 5 7 6 2 4 3 1
```

Comment: `Your choice of labels doesn't count against your code length.` mind elaborating? As it stands, I can hardcode the matrix into my code and claim it doesn't count against my score.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I was trying to say the length of your code is just the length of your code, and say, choosing multidigit labels doesn't cost anything extra. Looks like that line is more confusing that helpful, so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a+b*~0**a&7}
```

Ungolfed

```ruby
->a,b{ (a+b*(-1)**a) % 8}  
# for operator precedence reasons, 
#-1 is represented as ~0 in the golfed version
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoJAFEb39ynEgSi7if26ss0wy2GGYWYlLrQUFCINhULt1W1Agtodzsd3Hl32mopo2pxTzPp0nXnvwPPSRThOy8D3w5V/S@t@KAdwnNr5VdVQxBWWyQgjQBPFAe7wgCfcY4hbPCZW/n2b782lTBiupHbjuTAnCHvW@aXNr869a@uuBUIFl0YzBcQCZUobIBaENooBscAVMxqIUZpRLgUQzYziVEgbs1JIyoHY0UjBKUwf)

Uses the following coding numbers 0 to 7

In order native to the code:

```ruby
Native     Effect                    Codes per
Code                                 Question
0          rotate 0 anticlockwise    1C
1 /        flip in y=x               7E
2 /|       rotate 90 anticlockwise   2O
3 /|/      flip in x axis            5U
4 /|/|     rotate 180 anticlockwise  3M
5 /|/|/    flip in y=-x              8R
6 /|/|/|   rotate 270 anticlockwise  4P
7 /|/|/|/  flip in y axis            6T
```

In order per the question

```ruby
Native     Effect                    Codes per
Code                                 Question
0          rotate 0 anticlockwise    1C
2 /|       rotate 90 anticlockwise   2O
4 /|/|     rotate 180 anticlockwise  3M
6 /|/|/|   rotate 270 anticlockwise  4P
3 /|/      flip in x axis            5U
7 /|/|/|/  flip in y axis            6T
1 /        flip in y=x               7E
5 /|/|/    flip in y=-x              8R
```

**Explanation**

`/` represents a flip in the line `y=x` and `|` represents a flip in the y axis.

It is possible to generate any of the symmetries of the group D4 by alternately flipping in these two lines For example `/` followed by `|` gives `/|` which is a rotation of 90 degrees anticlockwise.

The total number of consecutive flips gives a very convenient representation for arithmetic manipulation.

If the first move is a rotation, we can simply add the number of flips:

```ruby
Rotate 90 degrees   +  Rotate 180 degrees = Rotate 270 degrees
/|                     /|/|                 /|/|/|

Rotate 90 degress   +  Flip in y=x        = Flip in x axis   
/|                    /                     /|/
```

If the first move is a reflection, we find we have some identical reflections `/` and `|` symbols next to each other. As reflection is self inverse we can cancel out these flips one by one. So we need to subtract one move from the other

```ruby
Flip in x axis     +  Flip in y=x        = Rotate 90 degrees
/|/                   /                    /|/ / (cancels to) /|

Flip in x axis     +  Rotate 90 degrees  = Flip in y=x
/|/                   /|                   /|/ /| (cancels to ) /
```

Comment: You can replace the `~0` with `7` because of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Great method and explanation! The way the flips cancel makes it really clear why the labels either add or subtract.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

Using integers \$0, 5, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6, 4\$ as labels.

```
BitXor[##,2Mod[#,2]⌊#2/4⌋]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfKbMkIr8oWllZx8g3PyUaSMU@6ulSNtI3edTTHav2PycxKTWnGKiy2kBHwVRHwUhHwVxHwVBHwVhHwUxHwaTWmiugKDOvxMHBQcO/tCS1KDpNRwGiCUbHKujrKYRkFKUmpkRDjdO1UwhKzEtPjbaIjdW0/g8A)

### Explanation:

The Dihedral group \$D_4\$ is isomorphic to the unitriangular matrix group of degree three over the field \$\mathbb{F}_2\$:

$$D_4 \cong U(3,2) := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_2\right\}.$$

And we have

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 1 & c_1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_2 & b_2 \\ 0 & 1 & c_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_1+a_2 & b_1+b_2+a_1c_2 \\ 0 & 1 & c_1+c_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$

which can easily be written in bitwise operations.

Comment: A pretty derivation -- I had not known about this isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 51 bytes

```
⌊#/4^IntegerDigits[#2,4,4]⌋~Mod~4~FromDigits~4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBdS8MwFH3Pr7i0MObI0GbpVh8KfRBBUBT1rVTItts2kLWSxi@G/QG6X@kfmYlZ9@JDknPOPTf3JBthatwII1diX6b7n91XeMqfrhqDFeoLWUnT5SGjnPLiZ/fd37TrnveXut34Ws9H@/FEiSWqbnJCVLplLKEQLygs7BlxC5hd0cJt5046Sz4JGU@etWwMCDBiqRDepKktqVGsUduLhrps1nKFHbQl@CEUtEuswdSisRvCcfid68gyuBdNhdk1NpWpM9Xfy7JU2AcQHB3BNOgf3dz@n2saEJ8ohdsXgzq/aztpZNvkipZ5SENWFHke0agoRlRRVXh7Z7TteDB2QOWvyh9bT0@zbRh@jrIs@3MWhxRDG3Gf8Ypalh/2Dfj@jCuD65QEETCYAYcY5rCAhHgWQWKZ1YhnzFZjpxHPZs7rNBJbNLc4shoDThx22swqHBjx1dhh5yG@Onde5zn8Vj7kTNMhW0H2vw)

Using labels `{228, 57, 78, 147, 27, 177, 198, 108}`.

These are `{3210, 0321, 1032, 2103, 0123, 2301, 3012, 1230}` in base 4. Fortunately, 256=4^4.

---

Lower-level implementation, also 51 bytes

```
Sum[4^i⌊#/4^⌊#2/4^i⌋~Mod~4⌋~Mod~4,{i,0,3}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDdboIwGL3vU3yBxDhToxQQdkHSB9gyo7sjmFQp0qSCgbqfGHmAbU@5F2GtFW920fac852v32kPTJX8wJTYsb5I@vXpkAYb8fvz5c6CjTnI7Mq/u@c674I7wGeB59i/ZKN@PJFsy2U7eUAyORMSYwgjDJE@vUADopcXme3RSPP4gtB4cmxEpYCBYlvJ4V2oUpOSs5w3@qKhLqpc7HgLdQF2CIbGJG5AlazSG4f78KXpoBRWrNpz@sSrvSqp7FaiKCTvHHDuDmfqdK9mbvfPNXWQTZTAy0nxJl3WrVCirlKJi9TFLsmyNPWwl2UjLLHMrL1Vje5YKz1gb69KX2tLZ/TsupcRpfTqzG4phjZkPuONN6L41G/gH0e@UzxPkOMBAR8CCGEBEcTIMg9izbSGLCO6GhoNWeYbr9FQqNFCY09rBAJksNF8rQRAkK2GBhsPstWF8RrP7bfSIWeSDNmy/g8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 22 bytes

A port of [my Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185151/9288). Using integers \$0, 6, 1, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4\$ as labels.

```python
lambda a,b:a^b^a/2&b/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvBCoJAFEX3fsVdhdIjdbICoS8xhffQoSc2irmor59GFDrLwznTd3mOzniLOx5@4Je0DCYpuZGGU3OQtAhauuEdiiojXAk54UYwhDPhQijqyI4zFOqwpWWEwDSrW1DlOO76pK7tPrGNldAnCdar/1@1/wE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>26</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:y+x*7**y&7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoIwFEVn@xU3HYziG6CIJCR8Se1Qg40kUEhB0359DWXQ5eQM5@bOYX1NVkTT3uOgx0en4Sk04eKzOsvCsY5Wj88FLSTvO07gS77RFckTnUgu/rzkin308N6XOUEQroQboSCUhIpQK8bM5BDQW@xtww6z6@0KmU6lOXlCOCtsnf91Kn4B) Port of my answer to [Cayley Table of the Dihedral Group \$D_3\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171962/cayley-table-of-the-dihedral-group-d-3). Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @NieDzejkob. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @xnor for suggesting the `and` (rather than `xnor`) operator. Uses the following mapping:

```python
 id | r1 | r2 | r3 | s0 | s1 | s2 | s3 
----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 6  | 1  | 3  | 5  | 7
```

Comment: You can replace `(-1)` with `7` because of modular arithmetic for -3 bytes.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Thanks! Shame that alephalpha golfed his answer down from 28 to 22 bytes though...

Comment: Nice solution! You can cut the parens by changing the operator precedence: `y+x*7**y&7`

Comment: @xnor Thanks, I'm ahead of alephalpha again!

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 165 bytes

```
Ans→L₁:{.12345678,.23417865,.34126587,.41238756,.58671342,.67583124,.75862413,.86754231→L₂:For(I,1,8:10fPart(.1int(L₂(I)₁₀^(seq(X,X,1,8:List▶matr(Ans,[B]:If I=1:[B]→[A]:If I-1:augment([A],[B]→[A]:End:[A](L₁(1),L₁(2
```

Input is a list of length two in `Ans`.
Output is the number at the `(row, column)` index in the table.

There could be a better compression method which would save bytes, but I'll have to look into that.

**Examples:**

```
{1,2
           {1 2}
prgmCDGF1B
               2
{7,4
           {7 4}
prgmCDGF1B
               5
```

**Explanation:**
(Newlines have been added for readability.)

```
Ans→L₁                              ;store the input list into L₁
{.123456 ... →L₂                    ;store the compressed matrix into L₂
                                    ; (line shortened for brevity)
For(I,1,8                           ;loop 8 times
10fPart(.1int(L₂(I)₁₀^(seq(X,X,1,8  ;decompress the "I"-th column of the matrix
List▶matr(Ans,[B]                   ;convert the resulting list into a matrix column and
                                    ; then store it into the "[B]" matrix variable
If I=1                              ;if the loop has just started...
[B]→[A]                             ;then store this column into "[A]", another matrix
                                    ; variable
If I-1                              ;otherwise...
augment([A],[B]→[A]                 ;append this column onto "[A]"
End
[A](L₁(1),L₁(2                      ;get the index and keep it in "Ans"
                                    ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

Here's a **155 byte** solution, but it just hardcodes the matrix and gets the index.
I found it to be more boring, so I didn't make it my official submission:

```
Ans→L₁:[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][2,3,4,1,8,7,5,6][3,4,1,2,6,5,8,7][4,1,2,3,7,8,6,5][5,7,6,8,1,3,2,4][6,8,5,7,3,1,4,2][7,6,8,5,4,2,1,3][8,5,7,6,2,4,3,1:Ans(L₁(1),L₁(2
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Comment: Couldn't you shave like one byte by using `0-7` to `1-8`

Comment: I could, but then I'd have to use two more to add one to each of the matrix's elements.  Good thought, however!

Comment: wrong, you can use any set of characters lol, so you don't havev to use two more

Comment: that may be true, but TI-BASIC's matrices are 1-indexed.  this submission relies on that to get the wanted value (if that's what you're implying.  correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: ah, forgot about that

Comment: You can store the big list in list A, so the second line is `{.123456 ... →A` (saving 1 byte). Elsewhere, you can just refer to it as `ʟA` (which is also 2 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```javascript
(x,y)=>y+x*7**y&7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc7LCoMwEIXhfZ/irBpjp@KlrYsSQV9DXIg3LNZILCV5@hSnm58PhgPzar/t3pl5@1xX3Q9@VD6w5KQq3MWGeRi6c@5LKNSICSnhRngQEkJGuBNyNM9TxXcx94Ig9vioSdhck7K5JmNn4th1et31MkSLnoIyerdb4KAK/GkPVvXI7zRSSv8D) Port of my answer to [Cayley Table of the Dihedral Group \$D_3\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171962/cayley-table-of-the-dihedral-group-d-3) but golfed down using the suggestions on my Python answer. Uses the following mapping:

```javascript
 id | r1 | r2 | r3 | s0 | s1 | s2 | s3 
----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
 0  | 2  | 4  | 6  | 1  | 3  | 5  | 7
```

Older versions of JavaScript can be supported in a number of ways for 22 bytes:

```javascript
(x,y)=>(y&1?y-x:y+x)&7
(x,y)=>y-x*(y&1||-1)&7
(x,y)=>y+x*(y<<31|1)&7
```

Comment: Small improvement - save a byte by currying input `x=>y=>(y&1?y-x:y+x)&7` then call your function using `f(x)(y)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
N⁹¡+%8
```

A dyadic Link accepting the first transform on the right and the second transform on the left which yields the composite transform.

Where the transforms are:

```
as in question:  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
transformation: id  90a  180  90c  hor  ver  +ve  -ve
  code's label:  0    2    4    6    1    5    7    3
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/vUePOQwu1VS3@//9v9t8cAA)** ...Or see [the table mapped back onto the labels in the question](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/vUePOQwu1VS3@RxvoGOmY6JjpGOqY6pjrGMceXn54X6bDo6Y1QKTi/h8A).

(The arguments could be taken in the other order using the 6 byter, `_+Ḃ?%8`)

#### How?

Each label is the length of a sequence of alternating `hor` and `+ve` transforms which is equivalent to the transform (e.g. `180` is equivalent to `hor, +ve, hor, +ve`).

The composition `A,B` is equivalent to the concatenation of the two equivalent sequences, and allows simplification to subtraction or addition modulo eight...

Using the question's `7, 4` example we have `+ve, 90c` which is:
`hor, +ve, hor, +ve, hor, +ve, hor  ,  hor, +ve, hor, +ve, hor, +ve`

...but since `hor, hor` is `id` we have:
`hor, +ve, hor, +ve, hor, +ve  ,  +ve, hor, +ve, hor, +ve`

...and since `+ve, +ve` is `id` we have:
`hor, +ve, hor, +ve, hor  ,  hor, +ve, hor, +ve`

...and we can repeat these cancellations to:
`hor`
..equivalent to subtraction of the lengths (`7-6=1`).

When no cancellations are possible we are just adding the lengths (like `90a, 180` \$\rightarrow\$ `2+4=6` \$\rightarrow\$ `90c`).

Lastly, note that a sequence of length eight is `id` so we can take the resulting sequence length modulo eight.

```
N⁹¡+%8 - Link: B, A
  ¡    - repeat (applied to chain's left argument, B)...
 ⁹     - ...times: chain's right argument, A
N      - ...action: negate  ...i.e. B if A is even, otherwise -B
   +   - add (A)
    %8 - modulo eight
```

---

It's also 1 byte shorter than [this implementation](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oZHuHY5NMjk46tP9/tKGOoYGOobmOoaWOkYmOhY6hqY5Z7MOdaw@3H1p6eF9CpsOjpjVApOL@HwA) using lexicographical permutation indexes:

```
œ?@ƒ4Œ¿
```

...a monadic Link accepting `[first, second]`, with labels:

```
as in question:  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
transformation: id  90a  180  90c  hor  ver  +ve  -ve
  code's label:  1   10   17   19   24    8   15    6
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```rust
|a,b|a^b^a/2&b/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLboMwFET3fMV0g0C6TcqzkaJ8CUoq0xrJESUpOGqVJt9O7XuJd12wmTNnsD1eJjt3Az6VGZIUvxHQa4tuN98UtTd1aA9qncftupy3C9M/Z/1u9Qd2iJuoyQg5oSCUhIpQE14Jmz1FTYhdZcOx556EOGehEu5JiAvZEe5JxUHNWcbctUpPJBNeMHQruSdBqCQT05Mg1LIjpiP7xzV71ep@4ku@cC3jvhzN73GzO41IDGE8facww2KtjNVjkq6u5pw8nksedzGOhNiBfxQekzagpkmP9k1/PSWd/9MxpUVp3ILDuEzmqvHsjp9uWbpH/rvPfw)

Port of alephalpha's Python answer. But shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org), <s>42 bytes</s> 19 bytes

```ml
\a b->and 7<|b+a*7^b
```

Port of the Neil's [Node.js version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185156/86885)

[Try it online](https://ellie-app.com/5vpH624w8rPa1)

**Previous version:**

```ml
\a b->and 7<|if and 1 a>0 then a-b else a+b
```

Comment: Nice first answer! I don't know how to program in Elm, but is it possible to remove spaces?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 nope, it's one of the main differences of ML-based languages that
`f x` is a function call, just like what `f(x)` means in C-like languages. And you can't help it. But it can be really nice and less cluttered in many non-golf scenarios. Elm doesn't have bitwise operators (like &) so `and x y` is just a plain function call here.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining!

Comment: @MilkyWay90 actually, I managed to cut off one space (and a byte) using pipe operator `<|` instead of parenthesis. Thanks for questioning that!

Comment: You're welcome! If you are interested in making a new solution, you could ask over on The Nineteenth Byte (our SE chatroom) for help. If you are creating a coding challenge, you could post it to The Sandbox (on meta) and post the link to the question on The Nineteenth Byte every day.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>82</s> 71 bytes

0-7
-11 bytes thanks to ASCII-only

```
lambda a,b:int("27pwpxvfcobhkyqu1wrun3nu1fih0x8svriq0",36)>>3*(a*8+b)&7
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##XcvdCoIwAEDha32K4UVutsC5UBHyRSpwK5ezmnP5@/QroyC6PB8cPXdVoyIrdgd7Y3d@ZoBhnknVQS9K9KinQZwaXl3ntiej6RVVPRGyCqf0MRjZhh6mMcpzGkAWpGuOVonVZtkFJHiLkPutGNOfojh@lWgMkEAqYJi6lDBFmessVv@Z895AIaDEoEbFPtuQI3Y/7Pv2CQ)

Comment: [80, python 2](https://tio.run/##TcfBCsIwDADQu1/hcXU9tEmbpYJfIsKSpUNB55Ad9OvrSfDd3vrZrs8FWptPd3moyV68HsfwjlzUBkWUFC3XCBNxBiI1Ayi1MFbFEiYSrgMHsDkn5fEsB@61j5e2vm7L1s1d9Mm53W/k8W/oybn2BQ), [76, python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnySohM69EQ8kwOy8r0dwkPyOn0Lwgy7DQ0MSyICc1Na/CwCzTMrEkJTHVPLvYMrHMyEBJx9hMMyE6UctCO0nbMPZ/QRHIgDQNQx0TTU0uGM9MxxiJZ6xjpqn5HwA)

Comment: [also 76](https://tio.run/##TcvRCsIgFADQ974i9hBedyFMcxr0Mbq4GNxtbrjIrzd6CHo8DyfXkpb50hrdOUzxEY4B40314jkX0fm6sluJtKJsxnFznOKrJm@pmOnKXN@771BbODspRZCuj3AaoOXt20koNACHnyzqP2m0AO0D), and -2 because `f=` can be removed since it isn't recursive

Comment: wait rip, it doesn't work

Comment: [here we go, 71](https://tio.run/##XcvdCoIwAEDha32K4UVutsC5UBHyRSpwK5ezmnP5@/QroyC6PB8cPXdVoyIrdgd7Y3d@ZoBhnknVQS9K9KinQZwaXl3ntiej6RVVPRGyCqf0MRjZhh6mMcpzGkAWpGuOVonVZtkFJHiLkPutGNOfojh@lWgMkEAqYJi6lDBFmessVv@Z895AIaDEoEbFPtuQI3Y/7Pv2CQ)

Comment: seems like you could do better with `int.from_bytes` and non-UTF encoding, but... not sure how to do that on TIO

Comment: @ASCII-only updated. Thanks! (Python is not my main language)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 17 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>a^b^a/2&b/4
```

Port of alpehalpha's Python answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCsIwFEVn@xXBQRJ8tlqrDpqMgiI4KDiIQhoTfVBSaKIWit8eK4rDhcvlHK5yA@UwLO9WLdB6@Jc2QhgeJBc5F/Kcn2WS9vIkC/PoIStSyFwXjnBi9fN4aoYwhRHMIIUxTCB7xftyg85TNo9MWWmpbvRjIUH7Uxlpos6hQq83aDV1vkJ7jdclWtolXfhC8U4XWnlac/EbVvai662hhiKjNWP9EWPtySu8AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 161 bytes

Choosing **COMPUTER** as labels.

```
val m="0123456712307645230154763012675446570213574620316574310274651320"
val s="COMPUTER"
val l=s.zipWithIndex.toMap
def f(a: Char, b: Char)=s(m(l(a)*8+l(b))-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5NS8NAFEXX5lcMWc3TWuZ7SiELKV24CBatuBAXL21qI5M0JIOopb99fKHw4Jx7F4877jBgOlVf9S6yEpsuO2c3@/rAWnKOy4dhwN/3lzg03ecHnHtiDB0/cOQC6GYMuZwE4JK@MbC2yIVU2ljnCcI7YwnSGu8IynlrjLNeKKmtN04JLSkaLYWiaKVWIs@mR2ORr57Kzet2/XwtQjHO/5r@rYnHx25f/8zjqcQ@m8bSnCVbHXGYseoqUIy85YEj3C7uAq8A7s0C0iWlddr8Aw)

Comment: this is code golf :| you're supposed to make it as short as possible

Comment: [88](https://tio.run/##Fcq9CsIwFAXg2T5F6JRoh/zcm4hQwdHByVEcbrWVSo1SgyClzx6vy/nOgfO@0ED52dzbSxIH6mMxFYtr24kHd0mb3TjS93RMYx9vZzW92DRE2UlTCVBqLj40iK7OfN3HVDX/VPW21MY6QB8YHTwgYxCCZ6wPCOAxaGscBvBWO8MTnNGWJxpndSlpuV41Ks/5Bw)

Comment: Yeah, I challenged myself to go with scala and real labels, not just native 0-7. Try to beat it.

Comment: [133](https://tio.run/##RY27CsJAEEVr8xUh1Y4v9r1BiCBiYSGKj0osNiaRSFwlCaKI376ONsJwzz3FcJujray/puf82IYLW7rgFXSyvAgv2IkdTeraPvebti7d6QCvG7KtHCmIJRTw@qEl7FsA3sHdVmGReHybu7affhOScUMiyriQShsENVoqBFPSaATXRkmplaGcCWWk5lQwVCkY5aiKCU4j0gxLl@WPJQ5DN@79NQUYyBh@200STZeL1W47W0f@7f3Mrz4)

Comment: [118 :P](https://tio.run/##RYu9CsIwFEZn@xSlU6JFdBOhgoQMDiEhJpM43P5JpUZpgiilzx6vLsLlnu8Mx1fQQ7yX16YKqYDOJWMyq5s2veEmsN0PA7xPxzB07nKm4wMZekdaAmRF8fIUyPo7KJ2SJ/RpW0TMDi7k5ffTYueJX3aubl4SKzrfLP5aUvqLfJExKZQ1XCOY5tYgpLGaIwTXxlpuNBNSGW25YEqiWiWZQDVSCZbFKUYe1Qc)

Comment: No bad, how about compressing the matrix somehow?

Comment: finally got it... [140](https://tio.run/##VY5RS8MwEMef7acIecq5xqGCjG4dSOiDDyGltk/iw2VLZ6TLRlJEKf3sNVWY@PLn7nc/7i7ssMPppN/NricSrUuG5GpvWnKMNcPs0Xv8ennuvXWHVxjak2e44VQoWTZ1UdFfpP@jc7R71jJMiYYFJRTG9Q/rHKOxGaf5QpxnT65P9ZyQiTf0@fCBHbH5iocb6/bmU0UJ1jbmVkPLdIpgumBIYPcP3F4zy29hebf4szXwFYzJvCbkl59kKaqiqYWqm6qQRVU3QqpSlEpIQadx@gY) for now (EDIT: or not :/)

Comment: [148](https://tio.run/##VY5BS8QwEIXP9leEnDLaKCqItNvDEnrwEFJqexIPk91UU7pZScqyUvrba6og7GV48817vAk7HHA56t7sRiLRumRKrvamI4eoGWZb7/H77XX01n28w9QdPcMNp0LJqm3Kmv4hfYm@ontkHcOUaLihhMKc/7LBMRqXeVkb4j17cWOq1wmZ@ERfTCcciC2eebi1bm/OKpogX2F/ATXktmN200PUKYIZgiGBPT5xe80sv4e7B97DnKzJUPz/JitRl20jVNPWpSzrphVSVaJSQgq6zMsP) (EDIT: wait it's not even symmetrical)

Comment: [115](https://tio.run/##NYs9C8JAEERr8yuWgHCnFn40KijIsYXFcst5V4nFRhNRYpQYBBF/@xkFh2Hea@a@l1LiNTvn@wZITlXySjqHvIBL60rmq7qW53bT1KfquNOvW8umrFShRA112wGIGn1F63fykBKKRWxv66oZZN/Vi2VqfEACyy6QsR7QsTfEARxatGwc@EAUvDPAFuEfdugtGAoWXWAg4x1bQgjepEq640l31pv2s5/o@I4RI38A)

Comment: Good job! I got [131](https://tio.run/##Jcxha4JQFAbgz/krLkLjnFatUghHChZ9qJCibS0IiWNd07i7il5iLfrtN11w4H144T3lgQTpLDrzg2IBpdK4GY0jj9lPZaB3vyjouvtQRSpPId7yKpWQEANBD6trM4J@DcS70biQYLGrqx2bJFS0WfQEul4JprMIs7GdhAtnk9jjbMOlP5fcGu23I3@7n1smCCBs2a8CInwbYMd2PK92c9CyXoZo1O9L15wsg9XX53Rt/hfCLbt/af6dqmQmj/y3q7KAcn3XeqpXDw) with matrix compressed into 32B ASCII string

Comment: [123?](https://tio.run/##TU3LCoJAFF3rV4hQzO2dCmGkoOEiQ5ReCCEx1piGjaEShfTt07gqOJwX3HuqM84xK@IbOdeShzMqNqJwIYl05x7huVWW@H3c1mVGrxE0D651TlGCMJoAx0DCaNoagI8oPHEuJQbjdytaD@KWwTArJOvrqLC1NFrrh1SziwOhlkuJujiFCys8uaqMqlFGL@Tl88/Q0/q/GMNYgaGmm@Z/11F6ancGYrtYGfLS94L9ztnI7MOYw4Iv)

Comment: Haha ".zipWithIndex.toMap" is way too long, any chance to shorten indexOf?

Comment: :/ even `def l(c:Int)=s.indexOf(c)` is shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 70 bytes

Choosing 0-7 native integers as labels.

Compressed the matrix into 32 byte ASCII string, each pair of numbers n0, n1 into 1 character c = n0 + 8*n1 + 49. Starting from 49 to that we don't have \ in the encoded string.

```
(a:Int,b:Int)=>"9K]oB4h]K9Vh4BoVenAJne3<_X<AX_J3"(a*4+b/2)-49>>b%2*3&7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJnHVc3FmZKappALZGskWjkWFSVWRgeXFGXmpcdqVhcA6ZKcPI00jUQNA00g0jWx0FFI1DCEsjU1a7nKEnMU0mz/AzV75pXoJIFITVs7JUvv2Hwnk4xYb8uwDBOn/LDUPEevvFRjm/gIG8eIeC9jJY1ELRPtJH0joDmWdnZJqkZaxmrm/2v//zf7bwwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{($^x*7**$^y+$y)%8}
```

Port of [Neil's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185157/14109).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczdCoMgAIbh43kVH2FD2yb7rUErupKGBwmOfsR2MBGv3eXxy/OawY5lnBz2qome0f5XVEVBe3egjufPkFI3osHrjCvuKHHBDQ9UbU22lNvUctaNQs5fbaS2K6@JWmxSpxZUw5PdKtNFTNIwvxGvGNVH0DcPgYvPomeWIdtciH8)