# Multiply elements of the dihedral group

Tags: code-golf, string, math, abstract-algebra

This is a copy cat question of [Simplify ijk string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/226278/simplify-ijk-string) applied to the other nonabelian group of order 8. See also [Dihedral group composition with custom labels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/dihedral-group-d4-composition-with-custom-labels).

### Challenge

Given a string made of `r` and `s` interpret it as the product of elements of the dihedral group \$D_8\$ and simplify it into one of the eight possible values `""`, `"r"`, `"rr"`, `"rrr"`, `"s"`, `"rs"`, `"rrs"`, and `"rrrs"`. The empty string denotes the identity element \$1\$.

The evaluation rules are as follows:
$$
rrrr = 1\\
ss = 1\\
sr = rrrs
$$
The multiplication on the dihedral group is associative but not commutative. This means that you may do the simplification in any order, but you cannot reorder the items.

For the I/O format, function parameter and return from a function should be done as a string or list. You may output any amount of leading and trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). You may use any other pair of distinct characters for `r` and `s` except for a tab, space, or newline. (If you really want to you can pick `r` or `s` to be whitespace, you can as long as you don't have leading or trailing whitespace.) It's also fine to use numbers for `r` and `s`, for example if you take `0` for `r` and `1` for `s`, it would be okay to do I/O like `[1, 0] ==> [0, 0, 0, 1]`.

### Test cases

```
"" -> ""
"r" -> "r"
"rrr" -> "rrr"
"s" -> "s"
"rs" -> "rs"
"rrs" -> "rrs"
"rrrr" -> ""
"rrrrrr" -> "rr"
"sr" -> "rrrs"
"rsr" -> "s"
"srsr" -> ""
"srr" -> "rrs"
"srs" -> "rrr"
"rsrsr" -> "r"
"rrsss" -> "rrs"
"sssrrr" -> "rs"
```

### Reference implementation

Here is a Javascript reference implementation.

```javascript
function f(x) {
  let lastx;
  while(lastx !== x){
    lastx = x;
    x = x.replace("rrrr", "");
    x = x.replace("sr", "rrrs");
    x = x.replace("ss", "");
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Can I/O be taken using different characters?

Comment: Also, do you mind adding a reference implementation?

Comment: Surprisingly no one asked about different characters on "ijk". I think it is okay, I will add that.

Comment: Can we use 1/0 for `r` and `s`?

Comment: 1 and 0 for `r` and `s` is fine. I think doing I/O as a list of `1` and `0` rather than strings / characters is also fine. I am not sure what the ideal wording for this is.

Comment: What should be the output for `ssr`? `r` or `srrrs`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing `r`, because `srrrs` is not one of the listed eight possible outputs.

Comment: "You may output any amount of leading and trailing whitespace", "You may use any other pair of distinct characters for r and s" but that would not work if I use whitespace as input characters and padding extra whitespaces to output

Comment: @tsh good point, this isn't a good specification. Maybe I can require the distinct characters to be nonwhitespace? Probably nobody used whitespace for `r` and `s` though. I do think to cause trouble you have to make a slightly bad faith interpretation of the rules...

Comment: @tsh I edited it and I think now it's okay and as permissive as possible. I just said you can't use the leading/trailing rule and use whitespace for `r`/`s`.

Comment: Can I use an output format that is different from the input format?

Comment: Can we output a pair of numbers representing the number of `r` and `s`?

Answer (score 14):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
~:/I.@,~4|[:-/1#;._1@,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY8/C8IwEMX3fopDwbOQphacUioBQRCcXKU4iG11ULgDF6VfPabN@afg4BBe3uPld7mzG2nACgqDCmZg/Ek0LLeblWtNutZWtfPHziRpNs71PrOqdHFU@zogY1FG9ely6x0x3tsyOh6aK3ShrWw90QtAzGGqkDDOfYkoWA6WMTz4qzSgko9Dl14abhy8F0FLM7Sky@8BP9BMLCQRFqKgiblPvHQzPxt8fWq4jwDQPQE)

Takes a boolean vector where `0` represents `r` and `1` represents `s`, and returns the result in the same encoding.

#### How it works

Imagine evaluating the chunks of \$r^n s r^m s\$ from the start. If we evaluate \$sr\$ in the middle \$m\$ times, we get \$r^{n+3m}s^2 = r^{n+3m}\$. We can repeat the process to the end. Let's represent the input as a sequence of integers which represent the number of \$r\$'s when separated by \$s\$'s, like `sssrrr -> [0, 0, 0, 3]`. Then the following holds:

- The alternating sum (`[a, b, c, d, ...] -> a - b + c - d + ...`) modulo 4 is the final number of \$r\$'s.
- The length plus 1 modulo 2 is the final number of \$s\$'s.

```
~:/I.@,~4|[:-/1#;._1@,]  NB. Input: a boolean vector
              1#;._1@,]  NB. Get the lengths of runs of r's between s's
        4|[:-/  NB. Alternating sum modulo 4 = the number of final r's
~:/             NB. Reduction by unequal on the original input,
                NB. i.e. the number of s's in the input mod 2
                NB. = the number of final s's
   I.@,~        NB. Reverse concat and generate that many 0's and 1's
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ṣ1ẈṚḅ3%4,SḂ$Ø.x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWGD3d1PNw56@GOVmNVE53ghzuaVA7P0Kv4/6hxX1Fx5qON64Do0M5HDTMPtz9qWvNwdzdQorgo8v//aHV1HQX1IjBRBKaKwWwICaOKYApgaiD8YigHRsO4UEmoqqLiYrAIkAJpjwUA)

Same algorithm as above. Doesn't feel well golfed to me though; maybe I missed some good alternative built-ins.

```
ṣ1ẈṚḅ3%4,SḂ$Ø.x  Input: a list of zeros and ones
s1Ẉ              Split at ones, then get length of each chunk
   Ṛḅ3%4         Reverse, evaluate in base 3, modulo 4
        ,        Pair with...
         SḂ$     Sum % 2
            Ø.x  Generate that many zeros and ones respectively
```

Comment: `Ṛḅ-` is `a-b+c-...`, not that it saves any bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## perl -p, 31 bytes

```
1while s/rrrr|ss//||s/sr/rrrs/;
```

Takes advantage of substitution returning truthy iff anything was substituted.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*-3 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

*-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
Δ48bγKT₄R:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/3BQTi6Rzm71DHjW1BFn9r9X5b8BlYGDAZchlAERgbAAWAQsCWYYgCkyAGSABkLCBoaEhFxCDlRkaAAA) Beats all other answers. Uses `0` for `r` and `1` for `s`.

```
Δ48bγKT₄R:  # full program
Δ           # while top of stack changes:
         :  # replace all instances of...
      T     # 10...
         :  # in...
            # implicit input...
            # (implicit) or top of stack if not first iteration...
     K      # with none of the elements of...
 48         # literal...
   b        # in binary...
    γ       # split into chunks of consecutive equal elements...
         :  # with...
       ₄    # 1000...
        R   # in reverse
            # implicit output
```

Comment: `õ:` can be replaced by `K`, which puts this back in the lead ;)

Comment: `8b` is the same as `₄` (1000).

Comment: @ovs Oh my god how could I forget xD

Comment: -2 bytes: [`Δ48bγKT₄R:`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/3BQTi6Rzm71DHjW1BFn9r9X5b8BlYGDAZchlAERgbAAWAQsCWYYgCkyAGSABkLCBoaEhFxCDlRkaAAA), it combines the removal of `0000` and `11` into `48bγK`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 18 bytes

```
{`rrrr|ss

sr
rrrs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxEgAgCEJ3vrKGhpYGaKt/N8ITfcehHHuuXnUaXVcCRBhVhQAEuiPGiWnSXxmBb@RW/mI59gA) Straightforward port of the reference implementation.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

- *[@dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) saves 12 bytes <sup><sub>by switch to Python 2 and finding out some bit-wise operators expression which I cannot understand</sub></sup>!*

```python
p=q=0
for b in input():p^=b;q+=~p/~b^p
print q%4*[0]+p*[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITv@xSLUPCnUFN6Sslb9CYK1aYoFLPGSPXiq6cRqymFXdhvdoahydSqPdtKPSQKDILAkuhECk@lscSmdUODCSNOhSivXSJmOs1lQUC6aQ12h0ucpXlCccZy6@IARk8cEN9185J404PkKEdZhUtFBHKsJBmOdO97m@Xgwm6PuIy72EpsF/31dXjwof3DvPAHP7K37p50A7b@2QZbyQc)

I/O as an array of integers, r = 0, s = 1.

JavaScript needs [too many bytes](https://tio.run/##dY7BTsMwDIbveQpfNidLl1HgtCmdeA5AWhSyqag0qV2hIcazlyQHbki28@t3/Nnv7tOxpz7N2zG@heVsF7bdszGGX82HS9LbbuuPSev9pO3DZpOaZCd7p9brJyL3JafVo26Vlml1f7shqmUOPHvHgcHCSZAgIsGCctSk6lQzKy5PLVUUo9jEzCJn/nYynIZ@lvgyojqIP3o97gq2g28B0OdlV0MhDc4HuTO7SwO@NHOxgIxwBGwR9oBNwQDEPHGWfdU@jhyHYIZ4kfF/SlspXCmEKo/@qMPyCw) to repeat some strings.

Comment: Following your method, I can shorten it to [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY1LCoMwEIb3c4pBKPFRqCldRXKL7qRCtSkKRccYqW68eqpYTSnMwHz/g6HRlE19tkXzUCjR8zxLspUxPBuNOVb1PNQbPxCUyTxpIznRacozAtJVbbA9XEKmWUQh65id6wBGjwIQ32X1UnjVvRKoBlX4y4sA1FAoMgLp3nU2vUEaL3vEZeaLr8R30V3fhANX2h3uhD/4kV10z8Qb8NXnG2xPPg), by switching to Python 2 and taking input as a list of `0` and `1` instead of a string.

Comment: A slightly-less-crazy looking variant of dingledooper's magic `~p/~b^p` is `1+p-b^p` (which gives `-1` instead of `3` but it's the same mod 4). There's also `(b==p)-p` which is longer is Python but might be shorter in other langs.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>54</s>  53 bytes

Expects a string with `1` for `s` and `2` for `r`. Returns another string in the same format.

```javascript
f=s=>s-(S=s.replace(/2222|1./,s=>s%3?"":2221))?f(S):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU89a8MwEN39Kw5BQSK2TJohkKBkytwhYwhByJKbYixzF0qh7W93T8GxukSD7t37gvuwn5YcXodb1cfGj2MwZHZUyaMhjX7orPOyfuX3s9R1mbSX1V6IDTNLpfZBHtWGxu2pABCiTD9OAydA0/6YGWC2ZveDo5nIKFOzafYj0cQySHXFudAh4sG6d0lgdvDNIt0QDPw7TddtCS7J4sJd@to3/ustSKfUlv3oOQpBcu6@u9hT7LzuYitJD7Y59I1cK1iAqLiCJyeetp/cOdX@qvEP)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = s =>           // f is a recursive function taking the input string s
  s - (            // test whether s is different from the updated string S
    S = s.replace( //   which is obtained by looking for the 1st occurrence
      /2222|1./,   //     of either "2222", "11" or "12"
      s =>         //     and replacing it with
      s % 3 ? ""   //     an empty string for "2222" and "11"
            : 2221 //     or "2221" for "12"
    )              //   end of replace()
  ) ?              // if s is not equal to S:
    f(S)           //   repeat the process with S
  :                // else:
    s              //   we're done: return s
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
œṣØ0Fœṣ1x4¤FœṣØ.j14BFµÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fx@eYeAGZhhWmBxa4gYV08syNHFyO7T18AQfiLJHDXMUdO0UHjXMfbhj0cMdXQ93TvN/uKPJ@XD7w93djxr3FRVzPdy95XD7o6Y1kf//KymBFCspcSkVQVhFIGYRjFME4hZDOMUgGSi7CMyB86BcmDYoB2EKyBCEkRCDihCmFsN5YE4RsqnFCEuKIPqgaiEOLS5GcQOQi7C2WAkA)

Uses `1` for `r` and `0` for `s`

### How it works

Jelly does not have a good time with replacements. Its translate atom, `y`, only handles replacing specific, individual values (such as integers) with others, and cannot work with replacing groups of items.

Instead, we split on the values we want to replace, and join with their replacements

```
œṣØ0Fœṣ1x4¤FœṣØ.j14BFµÐL - Main link. Takes a list of bits B on the left
                     µÐL - Apply the chain to the left on B until it reaches a fixed point
  Ø0                     -   Yield [0, 0]
œṣ                       -   Split around 0,0
    F                    -   Flatten
       1x4¤              -   Yield [1,1,1,1]
     œṣ                  -   Split around 1,1,1,1
           F             -   Flatten
              Ø.         -   Yield [0, 1]
            œṣ           -   Split around 0,1
                j14      -   Join with 14
                   B     -   Convert to binary
                    F    -   Flatten
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29</sup> 27 bytes

```
rplc&(sr`rrrs,,.rrrr`ss)^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCgIxDETvfkXwYF3oFs@FPQmePPkBurC4iAjKzP9TW6hNwB5CkscwkzzTNrhVpihOvBwk5hqDHC/nU8Lntez2xAyA3ofcMJPDNd7SsLkvj7c4J2OUNfe6w8lUdjQA/DRlrJRVxiZjUykzUKlxMyGWWq4W/AuHIhURnXii9w/NqWrZNcgjO79mWPzSFw)

- `` rplc&(sr`rrrs,,.rrrr`ss) `` Keep doing the needed replacements...
- `^:_` Until it stops changing

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>25</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
⁻⭆⪪θs×ι⊕⊗κ×r⁴×s﹪№θs²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3M6@0WCO4BMhJ900s0AguyMks0SjUUVAqVtLUUQjJzE0t1sjUUfDMSy5KzU3NK0lN0XDJL03KAdLZmkAAU6NUpKSjYAIUsOaCmAwVLgYK@@anlObkazjnl@YhmW0EUvz/f3HRf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Based on a method @Bubbler mentioned in chat. Explanation:

```
⁻⭆⪪θs×ι⊕⊗κ×r⁴
```

Split the input on `s`s, repeat alternate segments thrice, then use string substitution to reduce the length modulo `4`.

```
×s﹪№θs²
```

Output an `s` if there were an odd number of `s`s in the input. `⁻⁻θr¦ss` also works for the same byte count, but I can't find anything shorter.

<s>20</s> 19 bytes by taking I/O as strings of `0`s and `1`s:

```
⁻⭆⪪θ1×ι⊕⊗κ×0⁴×1﹪Σθ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxDgIhEER7v4JQ7SWYHMbO1saC5BL8AeSIEhe448DfX9eo00zmZWb8w1VfHBJNNeYGJua@gW0c7sYtYBeMDVYlpJaDEteYwgZRiUv2NaSQW5jhXPoN2Z8D69@Ro1TiyOC0@z7/sGZsytyxgO0JVh4cPi0iPdL@hW8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above but counts `1`s by taking the digital sum of the input.

Previous 25-byte string substitution answer:

```
Ｗ№θsr≔⪫⪪θsr¦rsssθ⁻⁻θ×r⁴ss
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDOb80r0SjUEdBqbhISVNTwbG4ODM9T8MrPzNPI7ggJxMhB6SKiouLQYxCTWuugKJMoEbfzLzSYigJVBiSmZtarKFUpKSjYKIJ0gFSr2n9/39x0X/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ№θsr
```

While the input contains `sr`...

```
≔⪫⪪θsr¦rsssθ
```

... replace all occurrences of `sr` with `rsss`.

```
⁻⁻θ×r⁴ss
```

Remove `rrrr` and `ss` and output the result.

I tried a numeric approach but it turned out to be slightly longer at 29 bytes:

```
≔⁰θＦＳ¿Σι≦⁻³θ≦⁺²θ§⪪”)∨'✂/Ｏ;”2θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsMgGIT3PsWP0y9Y@HXpkCljoIFAniCkmgrWpFFL395qsnW5O7j7bn5O@7xOLuc2BLt4JAFv3lzMugN2fktxjLv1C3IO1gCO6YW25H7aTuCuTcTe@hQE3A4WtAv6bzC42qvzeyiHEdvY@Yf@4rg5G5EpIpKK1KHFqpKSTABTjFeQNzlLyteP@wE) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is as strings of `0`s and `1`s. Explanation: The values are encoded to integers equivalent to `0..7` (modulo `8`) in the order , `01`, `0`, `1`, `00`, `0001`, `000`, `001`. A `1` subtracts the integer from `3` while a `0` adds `2` to the integer.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start with `0`.

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop over the input.

```
¿Σι
```

If the digit is nonzero, ...

```
≦⁻³θ
```

... then subtract the integer from `3`, ...

```
≦⁺²θ
```

... otherwise add `2` to it.

```
§⪪”)∨'✂/Ｏ;”2θ
```

Index into a look-up table to find the final result. (The number of zeros is actually given by `(x>>1)^(x&1)` and the number of ones by `x&1` but Charcoal has no bitwise XOR operator, so the best I could do was this look-up table.)

I was able to save a byte by using two variables:

```
≔⁰θ≔⁰ηＦＳ¿Σι≦¬θ≦⁺⊕⊗θη×0﹪η⁴×1θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3JCoMwEL33KwZPM5CCQm@eCr0ItQj2B6yOGoiJZunvp@kCQk9v4S393NnedCrGs3Ny0pgL2Kg87GpOajQWsNJr8K23Uk9IBHIEbMOCMvG6W3@Fm/GfAWDlePevPHpsVHACKt1bXlh7HvBiwkMl3Ii@R01a93iXCzvM8kxAbYagDM4CTkT/gSJ7f1EZY5HH41O9AA) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is as strings of `0`s and `1`s. Explanation: The two variables track the number of `1`s and `0`s. If there are an odd number of `1`s so far then each input `0` adds `3` otherwise it adds `1`.

```
≔⁰θ≔⁰η
```

Start with `0` `1`s and `0` `0`s.

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop over the input.

```
¿Σι
```

If the digit is nonzero, ...

```
≦¬θ
```

... then invert the parity of the `1`s, ...

```
≦⁺⊕⊗θη
```

... otherwise add `1` or `3` `0`s as appropriate.

```
×0﹪η⁴
```

Output the number of `0`s (mod 4).

```
×1θ
```

Output a `1` if appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```
[ [ "sr""rrrs""rrrr""" "ss"""[ replace ] 2tri@ ] to-fixed-point ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZGxjgIhEIb7fYq57dfiSk0u111sbMxVGwvEWUNcAWfmEo3x2fdQQFmVhvDly88/0Cktjobf5XzxM4UdksUe2PdGxNgtaLdfG6uCwsB4@EOrkcETipw8GSswq@aLKWxd31XVuYKw6hri@oDmK5wipLqElClFnihlziObs51wsu848Rzy4DF93IMiznK@kEbRRQiXDfmu82s0Pw1TyG@HpJRy448XYeb6TQhz2Tvgy9BCe2se@8Z5w@sHN2wtEPpeaYQVfAqZ77CLazpzxE3j3fXvVsNeeWBRejcZ/gE)

*-4 thanks to @Bubbler*

- Abuse the fact that strings don't require trailing whitespace in the version of Factor TIO uses.
- `2tri@` Call a quotation on three pairs of objects. e.g. `1 2 3 4 5 6 [ + ] 2tri@` -> `3 7 11`.
- `to-fixed-point` Call a quotation until its input stops changing.

Comment: [`2tri@` strikes again](https://tio.run/##bZGxjgIhEIb7fYq57dfiSk0u111sbMxVGwvEWUNcAWfmEo3x2fdQQFmVhvDly88/0Cktjobf5XzxM4UdksUe2PdGxNgtaLdfG6uCwsB4@EOrkcETipw8GSswq@aLKWxd31XVuYKw6hri@oDmK5wipLqElClFnihlziObs51wsu848Rzy4DF93IMiznK@kEbRRQiXDfmu82s0Pw1TyG@HpJRy448XYeb6TQhz2Tvgy9BCe2se@8Z5w@sHN2wtEPpeaYQVfAqZ77CLazpzxE3j3fXvVsNeeWBRejcZ/gE) :)

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks! And here I thought I had found a legitimate use of `ALIAS:`!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
λ88ok2‹o89k2⇩V;Ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB88ok2%E2%80%B9o89k2%E2%87%A9V%3B%E1%BA%8A&inputs=%60888999%60&header=&footer=)

Creative input abuse. Takes r as 9 and s as 8.

```
λ             ;Ẋ # Repeat until input doesn't change
 88o             # Get rid of 88s (`ss`)
    k2‹          # 10000 - 1 = 9999 (=`rrrr`)
       o         # Get rid of those as well
        89       # 89 (`sr`)
          k2⇩    # 10000 - 2 = 9998 (`rrrs`)
             V   # Replace (`sr` with `rrrs`)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

Uses `0` and `1` for `r` and `s`.

```
Δ•BƵ?ù•₂вb€¦ι`:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRfqVRUrKRkYKj0qGHh/3NTHjUscjq21f7wTiDjUVPThU1Jj5rWHFp2bmeC1f9akDKQcqBSnf/RSko6CkpFYKIITBWD2RASRhXBFMDUQPjFUA6MhnGhklBVRcXFYBEgBdIeCwA)

```
Δ           # Until the output doesn't change:
•BƵ?ù•₂в    # Compressed integer list
              [16, 1, 7, 1, 6, 17]
b€¦         # Convert to binary and remove most significant digit
              ["0000", "", "11", "", "10", "0001"]
ι`          # Split into two separate lists by alternating the values
              ["0000", "11", "10"], ["", "", "0001"]
:           # Replace
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 76 bytes

```java
s->{for(;s!=(s=s.replaceAll("rrrr|ss","").replace("sr","rrrs")););return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZOxbsMgEIZn@ykoS6BJeAHqSF26dcpYdaCOHeFiQHc4UuT62d2rkkode7ec7v5PP/xIDO7i9sPpc/VjTlDEQLOZig@mn2JbfIrm0dZ5@gi@FW1wiOLV@SjmWlDd91hcoXZJ/iRGUtWxgI/nt3cHZ9RzXb3cvZ5uwu7WDn2z4v4w9wmUxYdGYYMGuhxc2z2HoCRQfSHKnZT6V1ASgRakoNTaagtdmSAKtMta2bo6XrF0o0lTMZkOKSGqjdxse@NyDldFTlua9T9IYKDAgJHhy2F5MPDi8RJyvJFlzKN51qxLszICIsOd4L/P/fPRlnpZvwE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>21</s>  18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Not Jelly's forté! <s>Perhaps</s> There is [a clever way](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226380/53748) to do it though<s>?</s>.</sup>

```
2“Ð¡©¡¦Ñ‘ḃœṣjƭƒµÐL
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of `1`s (`r`) and `2`s (`s`), and yields the same.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/oUcOcwxMOLTy0EoiXHZ74qGHGwx3NRyc/3Lk469jaY5MObT08wef/o8Z9RcWZjzauO9z@cHc3mPf/f3FxcVFREQA)** (The footer translates from an `rs` string, calls the link and translates back.)
Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/oUcOcwxMOLTy0EoiXHZ74qGHGwx3NRyc/3Lk469jaY5MObT08wef/o8Z9RcWZjzauO9z@cHc3mMd1dM/h9kdNa9z//49WUtJRKgLhIhBZDGKBCShZBJWDSoN5xRAmlIJyIBIQBUXFxSA@kARpiwUA).

#### How?

```
2“Ð¡©¡¦Ñ‘ḃœṣjƭƒµÐL - Link: list of integers (in [1,2]): S
               µÐL - loop until no change f(X=S)->X:
2                  -   two
 “Ð¡©¡¦Ñ‘          -   code-page indices = [15,0,6,0,5,16]
         ḃ         -   to bijective base (2) -> [[1,1,1,1],[],[2,2],[],[2,1],[1,1,1,2]]
              ƒ    -   start with X and reduce using:
             ƭ     -     tie (call each of these two links in turn):
          œṣ       -       split (left) at sublists equal to (right)
            j      -       join (left) with (right)
                       }...i.e:
                              split at [1,1,1,1], join with []
                              split at [2,2], join with []
                              split at [2,1], join with [1,1,1,2]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 82 bytes

```
func[s][while[parse s[some thru[remove["rrrr"|"ss"]| change"sr""rrrs"]to end]][]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxDsMwCEXn5hSIvXvVoYfoihiimNSREjuCpF16d9dVJAcWnp/9kYxKKE8JxN14hzLuaSBj@sRpFlp7NQEjy4vAFnUnlSW/hVBr4RfNkL8wxD69BE3x76vaMkgKzMTGZcwq/RDBgDqohQhH1wba0Jo7yaP6kM@d3pz07LV77JJq1m4qHuOZVp3SVncRYMlzqP@4AV4feJxGMOZL@QE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash with sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>86</s></sup> 84 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)!!!

```bash
until [[ $a = $1 ]];do a=$1
set -- `sed 's/sr/rrrs/;s/rrrr\|ss//'<<<$a`
done
echo $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLasMwELz7KxYhyAMUkZYeQuxeQr8iTokbS1gQ5LKrQCDtt7urtU3ppQJ5xp7ZESN/NNQN/hYvKfQR/HL1GG4xhSscj6AbqEBv4XTatz00ld4W5BIYA2dyLSzIElpEJLunjFh/EVm7KMtSN@ei7aMr3KXrOWj4LnyPQBAiKKtA8WB@ogQw46z8zjmCmUyMLROKOXvHU8WPMkeZCOI0R5KAo4fm04jmXGaSR4q7FcArVXo51jJ2s9bGSA9aieh@xffN2v4ViUUPOk3W3NhwzVrpVCswr8CMmCnRg893y18UVBWjU/mCIXUuip7XJ4aYPEfc357q@@7A@7mO47y7kvvP@DIbfZBfMPwA)

Comment: [Shave a couple of bytes off](https://tio.run/##fVHLasMwELz7KxYhyAMUkZYeQuxeQr8iTokbS1gQ5LKrQCDtt7urtU3ppQJ5xp7ZESN/NNQN/hYvKfQR/HL1GG4xhSscj6AbqEBv4XTatz00ld4W5BIYA2dyLSzIElpEJLunjFh/EVm7KMtSN@ei7aMr3KXrOWj4LnyPQBAiKKtA8WB@ogQw46z8zjmCmUyMLROKOXvHU8WPMkeZCOI0R5KAo4fm04jmXGaSR4q7FcArVXo51jJ2s9bGSA9aieh@xffN2v4ViUUPOk3W3NhwzVrpVCswr8CMmCnRg893y18UVBWjU/mCIXUuip7XJ4aYPEfc357q@@7A@7mO47y7kvvP@DIbfZBfMPwA).  But is much shorter if you just use [sed and no bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226396/11259).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma sed and no bash doesn't make sense, since you already have a sed answer, but bash without sed is possible,

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nice ones - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```r
function(x){while(x!=(x=sub("rrrr|ss","",sub("sr","rrrs",x))))0;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO6PCMzJ1WjQtFWo8K2uDRJQ6kICGqKi5V0lJR0wALFRUA2UBAoVKEJBAbWFbX/0zSUlDS50iDKESwYu7i4GMz@DwA)

*-2 bytes thanks to [iota](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99986/iota)*

Applies reference implementation.

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrO6PCMzJ1WjQtFWo8K2uDRJQ6kICGqKi5V0lJR0wALFRUA2UBAoVKEJBAbWFbX/0zSUlDS50iDKESwYu7i4GMz@DwA) by using the same approach as [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226371/99986).

Comment: @iota thanks! I had that idea and recall testing it without success, but looks like my memory is failing me...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 90 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,s=str.replace:f(s(s(s(x,"r"*4,""),"ss",""),"sr","rrrs"))if x not in"rrrs"else x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsIwDIbPy1NYPiVTxmU7IXXXvcBeIAUXIoUS2QGKJp6dpU1KQTnk/@z4/514Tftj/3ln2nlJxNAAolLxGtn3KdN0K7Wlrkg9mLV624Vj6wLMU@rtaX64d01wh3brYLDSSOIVUwxuQ@tOy3QGi4zvXxbRWBTBKjgLZhY0xncwQH9M4PtSoiCUrS97Hwh@@UR5C2ehzYEHFzWdXbD5cTwlbVYSg08a4eMbstfLdp12uVD/pzv88Wfq4S9vyLlzs0BDpE2iba21Y03cZV15tjI30AeXNnuSqTUHNNDeDJo7lnRU@aeT4lHyDDyiFJCxUzVP8KCK81iFxWU0WSyLES@u8qAJ@NlVlhAuc/VtWVTkZYeMS6zgPw)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8, 86 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,r=str.replace:f(s)if s!=(s:=r(r(r(s,"rrrr",""),"ss",""),"sr","rrrs"))else s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BC0IhEITv/Qrbk4J06RIP/DFWSg/sJTNe@vXmIwrU3ct@M8Ow@V0er@18yag1uuSf17tXtHAsOCHk5G9hiZpmjYpHp7k46H1pBW3Eihgr5O/YlaZTjAmJQbFmrFvRUTffHP6AntAze3fAiTG1TYVDgqM9CVNgLBgrQfaZxt836gc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╚ò/i»┬⌐ÇÑ ╒‼î┐╟▌z¥²
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c8952f69afc2a980a520d5138cbfc7dd7a9dfd&i=%22%22%0A%22r%22%0A%22rrr%22%0A%22s%22%0A%22rs%22%0A%22rrs%22%0A%22rrrr%22%0A%22rrrrrr%22%0A%22sr%22%0A%22rsr%22%0A%22srsr%22%0A%22srr%22%0A%22srs%22%0A%22rsrsr%22%0A%22rrsss%22%0A%22sssrrr%22%0A&m=2)

Plain Regex.

Bubbler's method is a bit long in Stax since zeroes get converted to spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 26

```
:
s/rrrr|ss//
s/sr/rrrs/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsAwCAN3/yVi73vSoUtT2Rn79lIDwnCc0DkzDyjoeqUIs1inAjsThBkC3R22aWlSrR4NJUpTEpx6@9azr3UrB38)

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 21 bytes

```
/sr/rrrs//rrrr///ss//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X7@4SL@oqKhYH0QW6evrFwOZ/4uLi4G8/wA)

Input is appended to the end of the code.

A straightforward implementation of the three evaluation rules.  Note that after every `sr` is replaced by `rrrs` recursively, the resulting string is of the form \$r^xs^y\$, and neither of the remaining rules will change this fact.  Thus, we do not need to revisit `sr -> rrrs` after applying the other two rules.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 75 bytes

```bash
a=${1//sr/rrrs};a=${a//rrrr/};a=${a//ss/};[ "$a" = "$1" ]&&echo $1||. $0 $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWpdpQX7@4SL@oqKi41hrET9QHcYr04bziYiA7WkFJJVFJwRZIGSopxKqppSZn5CuoGNbU6CmoGCioJP7//7@4uBioEQA) Why use sed when you don't need to?

Answer (score 2):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 81 bytes

```
mod D is inc LIST{Nat}. eq 0 0 0 0 = nil . eq 1 1 = nil . eq 1 0 = 0 0 0 1 . endm
```

#### Example Session

```
             \||||||||||||||||||/
           --- Welcome to Maude ---
             /||||||||||||||||||\
         Maude 3.1 built: Oct 12 2020 20:12:31
         Copyright 1997-2020 SRI International
           Fri May 28 22:50:23 2021
Maude> mod D is inc LIST{Nat}. eq 0 0 0 0 = nil . eq 1 1 = nil . eq 1 0 = 0 0 0 1 . endm
Maude> red nil .
reduce in D : nil .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result List{Nat}: nil
Maude> red 0 .
reduce in D : 0 .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result Zero: 0
Maude> red 0 0 0 .
reduce in D : 0 0 0 .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 0
Maude> red 1 .
reduce in D : 1 .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NzNat: 1
Maude> red 0 1 .
reduce in D : 0 1 .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 1
Maude> red 0 0 1 .
reduce in D : 0 0 1 .
rewrites: 0 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 1
Maude> red 0 0 0 0 .
reduce in D : 0 0 0 0 .
rewrites: 1 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result List{Nat}: nil
Maude> red 0 0 0 0 0 0 .
reduce in D : 0 0 0 0 0 0 .
rewrites: 1 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0
Maude> red 1 0 .
reduce in D : 1 0 .
rewrites: 1 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 0 1
Maude> red 0 1 0 .
reduce in D : 0 1 0 .
rewrites: 2 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NzNat: 1
Maude> red 1 0 1 0 .
reduce in D : 1 0 1 0 .
rewrites: 3 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result List{Nat}: nil
Maude> red 1 0 0 .
reduce in D : 1 0 0 .
rewrites: 3 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 1
Maude> red 1 0 1 .
reduce in D : 1 0 1 .
rewrites: 2 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 0
Maude> red 0 1 0 1 0 .
reduce in D : 0 1 0 1 0 .
rewrites: 3 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result Zero: 0
Maude> red 0 0 1 1 1 .
reduce in D : 0 0 1 1 1 .
rewrites: 1 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 0 1
Maude> red 1 1 1 0 0 0 .
reduce in D : 1 1 1 0 0 0 .
rewrites: 12 in 0ms cpu (0ms real) (~ rewrites/second)
result NeList{Nat}: 0 1
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod D is
    inc LIST{Nat} .

    eq 0 0 0 0 = nil .
    eq 1 1 = nil .
    eq 1 0 = 0 0 0 1 .
endm
```

I chose to encode `r` as `0` and `s` as `1`. (It would cost 19 more bytes to use `r` and `s` directly instead.)

I am shocked and thrilled that Core Maude is actually competitive in this question! Maude's built-in list module implements lists using the `__` operator (juxtaposition), which is associative and has `nil` as its identity. This means an equation can match any sublist. Since this is just "reduce until done", we don't even need our own function symbol to separate input from output.

We could probably get away with shaving off one byte, but it would not technically be a correct Core Maude program anymore. The existing Maude interpreter does not differentiate between protecting (`pr`) and including (`inc`) modules, but according to the spec our equations would not be valid with protecting.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>118</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>96</s></sup> 95 bytes

```c
i;b;p;q;f(char*s){for(;s[i];q+=~p/~b^p)p^=b=s[i++]-48;for(i=p+q%4;i--;*s++=48^i<p);i=p=q=*s=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLBbtswDL3nKzgDheUoRpM1A7qp6g7DviJxgESVW2Wpq4guli1IP30eJcuGU/RQoAYsUuTj06Mold8r1TRGbIQVe1Ey9bB2Y8yO5ZNjAhemEHsuX@zly2ZlM7uSG0lBzot8fi08xkjL9xdzYfJcjJFzOb9emRubCUrIvRyjnIpTY6oaHtemYtnoOAL6wjFQa6xxUYCEow8myQQSFxYXDAa/XTvjOkCH8atHxV1nu21LEcPEgiFCxtefxECNPlitan0XBb1DjT/Z6w756PlMgMaG2ii2IqP483AgPVOiHrT6pR0JAS8lWR5@fl4evv6g/4snGOyvukoaBjB/z6a60wcqm4ro3gCav/qpZF2D2WUMjPuIAM4DOoN2QIMhEVc7qAAoRJ/3p@0oi7Xb6YrVmTgrhc1zWS52wGE2KCKwsn@Yz01gWNI3sG3Fh@ptIWDLedbtKMWiK2WK6XdIZyl8g3SaDqkC5mPcM8@Ngdulrzqjt0Lg/r28dS92jUiYT77dR8v0BF5Jso5gJUuWyQUuE8hvIXq0VDTkuq2Y9I/BMxaR4DQ6Nf9UuVvfY5P//g8)

Uses `'0'` for `'r'`, `'1'` for `'s'`, and [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)'s formula for [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226384/9481).